Binder node "vndbinder" for waydroid not found
I'm confused, I've JUST installed debian 12 (kde), so this problem can’t just happen to me, right?
When i run sudo waydroid init, it prints following error:
Binder node "vndbinder" for waydroid not found
my waydroid log output:
(021709) [21:26:03] % modprobe binder_linux devices="anbox-vndbinder,anbox-hwbinder"
(021709) [21:26:03] ERROR: Binder node "vndbinder" for waydroid not found
(021709) [21:26:03] See also: <https://github.com/waydroid>
(021709) [21:26:03] Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/waydroid/tools/__init__.py", line 64, in main
   actions.init(args)
 File "/usr/lib/waydroid/tools/actions/initializer.py", line 110, in init
   setup_config(args)
 File "/usr/lib/waydroid/tools/actions/initializer.py", line 97, in setup_config
   helpers.drivers.setupBinderNodes(args)
 File "/usr/lib/waydroid/tools/helpers/drivers.py", line 141, in setupBinderNodes
   raise OSError('Binder node "vndbinder" for waydroid not found')
OSError: Binder node "vndbinder" for waydroid not found

(021724) [21:26:18] % tail -n 60 -F /var/lib/waydroid/waydroid.log
(021724) [21:26:18] *** output passed to waydroid stdout, not to this log ***
(021894) [21:26:58] % modprobe binder_linux devices="anbox-vndbinder,anbox-hwbinder"
(021901) [21:26:59] % modprobe binder_linux devices="anbox-vndbinder,anbox-hwbinder"
(021912) [21:27:01] % modprobe binder_linux devices="anbox-vndbinder,anbox-hwbinder"
(021918) [21:27:03] % modprobe binder_linux devices="anbox-vndbinder,anbox-hwbinder"
(021935) [21:27:07] % modprobe binder_linux devices="anbox-vndbinder,anbox-hwbinder"
(022518) [21:29:47] % modprobe binder_linux devices="anbox-vndbinder,anbox-hwbinder"
(022518) [21:29:47] ERROR: Binder node "vndbinder" for waydroid not found
(022518) [21:29:47] See also: <https://github.com/waydroid>
(022518) [21:29:47] Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/waydroid/tools/__init__.py", line 64, in main
   actions.init(args)
 File "/usr/lib/waydroid/tools/actions/initializer.py", line 110, in init
   setup_config(args)
 File "/usr/lib/waydroid/tools/actions/initializer.py", line 97, in setup_config
   helpers.drivers.setupBinderNodes(args)
 File "/usr/lib/waydroid/tools/helpers/drivers.py", line 141, in setupBinderNodes
   raise OSError('Binder node "vndbinder" for waydroid not found')
OSError: Binder node "vndbinder" for waydroid not found

(023208) [21:34:04] % modprobe binder_linux devices="anbox-vndbinder,anbox-hwbinder"
(023701) [21:41:17] % tail -n 60 -F /var/lib/waydroid/waydroid.log
(023701) [21:41:17] *** output passed to waydroid stdout, not to this log ***

if you had the same issue, please share the solution. I searched on the Internet and did not find any similar issue

You most likely have an instance of anbox installed. In my case I had the snap version installed and I had to remove it first

$ snap remove anbox
$ sudo waydroid init
$ sudo reboot

